# AutoCompleteTextView with Arrayadapter - does it have its own brain?

Tags: sqlite, autocomplete, autocompletetextview

Here is my quandry...

I have an AutoCompleteTextview which I am populating by getting data from sqlite database.

When I type 'mat' in the autocompletetextview, the query that gets the data, the resultset looks like the following:

```
35-Mathoura Rd/Toorak Rd
59-Airport West/Matthews Ave
58-Marshall Rd/Matthews Ave
57-Hawker St/Matthews Ave
56-Earl St/Matthews Ave
55-Cameron St/Matthews Ave
54-Fullarton Rd/Matthews Ave
54-Fullarton Rd/Matthews Ave
53-Keilor Rd/Matthews Ave
.
.
.
.
.
more data
```

However, in the autocomplete dropdown list, the results are as follows:

```
Matthew Cl/Westmill Dr
Matson Dr/Glenfern
Matlock Rd/Lewis St
.
.
.
and so on.
```

I would like to know why the results from database and the ones displayed do not match exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it does. Had to write my own adapter to achieve the ordering that I wanted.